# How can I add two and more buttons in python turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make 2 and more buttons working

I tried to change def name,add another py file and I have one result.Just one button was working

```
t.setpos(-170,-30)
t.pendown()
t.forward(300)
t.left(90)
t.forward(150)
t.left(90)
t.forward(300)
t.left(90)
t.forward(150)
t.penup()
t.write("START", font=("Calibri",80))
def btnclick(x,y):
   if x>-170 and x<130 and y>-30 and y<120:
      print("hello") 
turtle.onscreenclick(btnclick)
turtle.listen()
t.setpos(170,-30)
t.pendown()
t.left(90)
t.forward(300)
t.left(90)
t.forward(150)
t.left(90)
t.forward(300)
t.left(90)
t.forward(150)
t.penup()
t.write("CREDITS", font=("Calibri",80))
def btnclick(x,y):
   if x>170 and x<430 and y>-30 and y<120:
      print("hello1") 
turtle.onscreenclick(btnclick)
turtle.listen()
```

I want to make 2 and more buttons working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have redefined the function `btnclick()` hence definition changes and previous one will not work. You should use if else in `btnclick()` to identify the clicktype and then suitable code inside the condition.
Here all three buttons are working fine simultaneously...
e.g.,

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.pendown()
t.forward(300)
t.left(90)
t.forward(150)
t.left(90)
t.forward(300)
t.left(90)
t.forward(150)
t.penup()
t.write("START", font=("Calibri",80))
def btnclick(x,y):
    if x>-170 and x<130 and y>-30 and y<120:
        print("hello") 
    elif x>170 and x<430 and y>-30 and y<120:
        print("hello1") 
    elif x>-30 and x<-30+300 and y>-180 and y<-180+150:
        print('hello2')
turtle.onscreenclick(btnclick)
turtle.listen()
t.setpos(170,-30)
t.pendown()
t.left(90)
t.forward(300)
t.left(90)
t.forward(150)
t.left(90)
t.forward(300)
t.left(90)
t.forward(150)
t.penup()
t.write("CREDITS", font=("Calibri",80))
t.setpos(-30,-180)
t.pendown()
t.left(90)
t.forward(300)
t.left(90)
t.forward(150)
t.left(90)
t.forward(300)
t.left(90)
t.forward(150)
t.penup()
t.write("UB", font=("Calibri",80))
turtle.done()
```

I think this should help you....